# HTML remove vertical spacing from "a" element

Tags: html, css

I have the below code which results in a noticeable vertical space between 'client' and 'title'.  When I remove the "a" element from client the gap disappears.  How can I remove the gap whilst keeping the "a" element?

```
echo "<h4><a href='";
    echo the_permalink();
    echo "'>";
    echo get_field('client');
    echo "</a></h4>";

    echo "<h4><a href='";
    echo the_permalink();
    echo "'>";
    echo the_title();
    echo "</a></h4>";
```

Comment: Post also your CSS how <h4> and <a> are styled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical space is most likely margin and/or padding on the `h4` elements. The solution in this case is to use only 1 `h4` that contains 2 links, possibly with a `<br>` so the second link appears on a new line.

So, don't close the first `h4`, and don't open the second `h4`. Or don't use `h4` at all, but that depends on what the header represents.